# Diamond shape with rounded corners and background image

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

I need to achieve this:

[image: diamond with image and rounded corners]

Note that the container is rotated but the picture isn't..

And for now I did:

```css
div.img {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 320px;
}
div.img img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%
}
div.img span {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  transform: rotate(133deg);
  background: white
}
div.img span.tl {
  top: -36%;
  left: -36%
}
div.img span.bl {
  bottom: -36%;
  left: -36%
}
div.img span.br {
  bottom: -36%;
  right: -36%
}
div.img span.tr {
  top: -36%;
  right: -36%
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/nature/?v2s" alt="Pellete">
  <span class="tl"></span>
  <span class="bl"></span>
  <span class="tr"></span>
  <span class="br"></span>
</div>
```

But I can't find a way to add the rounded corners with this solution...

I thought that maybe would be possible to create a shape and use it as a mask with css and just add it in the container with higher z-index,

Can you think of a better way ?

PD: As a last resort, I'll ask the designer to create a .svg (because with responsiveness with an image won't render properly) with that shape..

Comment: Why not create the rotated frame with the image and the background in a photo editor and use a simple rectangular image in your HTML?

Comment: @amit in that case I'would use an .svg because its a flexible width container... Harry

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet I think the right approach is, as you suggested, "create a shape and use it as a mask with css and just add it in the container with higher z-index."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you plan on svg why not use it straight away. You don't need to ask your designer to make it either, you can code it inline, control the rounded corners, the shape... and it's scalable :

```css
svg{display:block;width:30%;height:auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="1 1 8 8">
  <pattern id="image" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <image xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/kreZqnx.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="10" width="10" />
  </pattern>
  <path d="M5.5 1.5 L8.5 4.5 Q9 5 8.5 5.5 L5.5 8.5 Q5 9 4.5 8.5 L 1.5 5.5 Q1 5 1.5 4.5 L4.5 1.5 Q 5 1 5.5 1.5z" fill="url(#image)" />
</svg>
```

Other points are:

- you can maintain boundaries of the shape for user interactions (click or hover)
- display it on any background (plain color gradient, background image...)

Example :

```css
#shape:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  fill:gold;
}
body{
  background:url('http://i.imgur.com/5NK0H1e.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
}
svg{display:block;width:50%;height:auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="1 1 8 8">
  <pattern id="image" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <image xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/kreZqnx.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="10" width="10" />
  </pattern>
  <path id="shape" d="M5.5 1.5 L8.5 4.5 Q9 5 8.5 5.5 L5.5 8.5 Q5 9 4.5 8.5 L 1.5 5.5 Q1 5 1.5 4.5 L4.5 1.5 Q 5 1 5.5 1.5z" fill="url(#image)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: You made my day!!! How great is that?! I just would like to it have less "padding" I tried changing numbers but I don't understand. How would it be?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet happy to have helped! For the padding around the shape, the simplest is to modify the `viewbox` attribute of the `svg` tag. I changed it  to `viewbox="1 1 8 8"` in the answer snippets so you can see. [More info on the  viewbox attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox).

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, you could I do that the border-radius is 8px ?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet sorry but I can't make the border radius to 8px exactly but I reduced it in this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/jjvv635g/

Comment: No worries! Thank you so much!

Comment: I wish I could understand this ( do you perhaps know an online editor? )  now my designer even says that it should be 4px radius.. :__(

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet it is pretty simple in fact. Concerning the path element, I learn most of it on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths). In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/epvkdn8o/) I put each path command on a new line (see the `d` attribute). `M` is move too (a bit like start path from). `L` is draw a line to. `Q` is a quadratic Bezier curve command, you will find all info about that in the MDN tutorial. All the numbers are coordinates in the system defined by the `viewbox` attribute on the `svg` element.

Comment: Thanks a lot, again! I'll dig into that and see If I come with it!

Answer (score 5):

CSS3 `clip-path` is definitely the most flexible approach - you can use SVG to define image clips at your desire.

Here's an [amazing tool](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/). However, it doesn't provide the round corner square by default, so you may have to write your own SVG (doesn't really difficult though).

If you want to know more deep inside, read [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).

**Please note**: this feature is not supported by all major browsers, check [**caniuse**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) for browser compatibility.

An example here regarding your post:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath);
  clip-path: url(#svgPath);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/nature/?v2s">
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath">
      <path d="M 95 5 Q 100 0 105 5 L 195 95 Q 200 100 195 105 L 105 195 Q 100 200 95 195 L 5 105 Q 0 100 5 95 Z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: It is a good solution if one don't need to support Microsoft IE or Edge, but I think its to many who use that browser to rule them out, and if OP still needs to use SVG, no need for `clip-path` and `translate`

Comment: Why not use the SVG clipPath instead of CSS clip-path? It has better browser support.

Answer (score 3):

This could might be a start.

Set the pseudo element's width/height to its diagonal (√ 2 × width = 1.4142...) and then adjust it to appear in the center.

```css
div.img {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 10%;
}
div.img:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -21%;
  left: -21%;
  width: 142%;
  height: 142%;
  content: "";
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/320/320/nature/4);
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.img2 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 10%;
}
div.img2 img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -21%;
  left: -21%;
  width: 142%;
  height: 142%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
</div>
<div class="img2">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/nature/4" alt="img">
</div>
```

Comment: Loooks good, I'll test if can pass the background image as a data-value and let you know, thanks!

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet If you need to set the image source inline, like with `img`, I added the exact same code using one, as you can't set the pseudo image using `data-*`

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I updated my answer where border has % and as well % on images widht/height which make them scale and be responsive.

Answer (score 2):

just use **CSS3 transform** for parent DIV

```css
div.img {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin:50px;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);  /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Safari & Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotate(45deg);  /* Opera */
  border-radius: 8px;
}
div.img img {
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);  /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg); /* Safari & Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);  /* Opera */
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/nature/?v2s" alt="Pellete">
</div>
```

Comment: Close! I tried that, but this way the image is rotated and it can't, if you add -45deg to it to restore it, it won't render this way... I am playing with transform-origin with no success... any ideas?

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, I'll see if with % work, it's a responsive site... and let you know

Answer (score 2):

You can use css `clip-path`.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #FEF7E4;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
div.img {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 320px;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(155px at center);
}
div.img img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/nature/?v2s" alt="Pellete">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -- an absolutely positioned mask over an absolutely positioned image.

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 320px;
}

.image-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image-container .mask {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 150px solid #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 160px;
  top: -102px;
  left: -102px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* Safari & Chrome */
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* Opera */
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/nature/?v2s" alt="Pellete">
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

You may have to play around with the exact pixel values.

Comment: I need it with % because as I mentioned this has to be responsive, and I am trying with no luck.... because border don't admit % is very difficult..

Comment: Then SVG might be best.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.content {
  background-color: #FEF7E4;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
div.img {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin:50px;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);  /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Safari & Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotate(45deg);  /* Opera */
  border-radius: 8px;
}
div.img img {
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);  /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg); /* Safari & Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);  /* Opera */
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="img">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/nature/?v2s" alt="Pellete">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but it can be done simply using a background image.

```css
.container {
  padding: 4rem;
  background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/800);
  background-size: cover;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: #000;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5rem;
  left: -1.5rem;
  right: -1.5rem;
  bottom: -1.5rem;
  background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/500);
  background-size: cover;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.box:hover:after {
  background: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="116" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 135 135">
<pattern id="amw-image" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"><image height="1" width="1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xlink:href="https://kinoscenariy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Emma-Stone-on-the-set-of-Maniac-in-NYC-27-150x150.jpg"></image></pattern>

<path fill="url(#amw-image)" stroke="#dd3333" stroke-width="0.7" d="M59.014718625761 3.8603896932107a12 12 0 0 1 16.970562748477 0l55.154328932551 55.154328932551a12 12 0 0 1 0 16.970562748477l-55.154328932551 55.154328932551a12 12 0 0 1 -16.970562748477 0l-55.154328932551 -55.154328932551a12 12 0 0 1 0 -16.970562748477 Z"></path>
</svg>
```